# What is the correct way to access the `export default` in KotlinJS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I am playing with Vue and KotlinJS and thought that I can simply get access to the Vue observer functions like `Vue.set` this way:

```
@JsModule("vue")
@JsName("Vue")
open external class Vue {
    companion object {
        fun <T> set(target: Any, key: String, value: T): T
        fun <T> set(target: Array<T>, key: Int, value: T): T
    }
}
...
Vue.set(state.todos, 1, todo)
```

However I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $module$vue.set is not a function

where `$module$vue = require("vue")`.

What is working though is this (notice the `object default` instead of `companion object`:

```
@JsModule("vue")
@JsName("Vue")
open external class Vue {
    object default {
        fun <T> set(target: Any, key: String, value: T): T
        fun <T> set(target: Array<T>, key: Int, value: T): T
    }
}
...
Vue.default.set(state.todos, 1, todo)
```

Why is that and is there a good way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `@JsName("Vue")`, try: `@JsName("default")`